# Using ccache with '-specs=nano.specs'

Tags: ccache, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm trying to cross-compile with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, which needs the flag `-specs=nano.specs`.

Unfortunately that seems to break ccache. In the logs I now have:

```
[2024-01-24T10:36:58.306578 191738] Failed to lstat nano.specs: No such file or directory
[2024-01-24T10:36:58.306581 191738] While processing -specs=nano.specs: nano.specs is missing
[2024-01-24T10:36:58.306602 191738] Failed; falling back to running the real compiler
```

I tried to add a `--ccache-skip` in front of `specs=nano.specs` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

How can I tell ccache to ignore the nano.specs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--ccache-skip` flag should probably work as expected, but in the meantime there are work-arounds:

1. Use [ignore_options/CCACHE_IGNOREOPTIONS](https://ccache.dev/manual/4.9.html#config_ignore_options)
2. Specify the full path to the nano.specs. For example, `-specs=/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/lib/nano.specs`.

I ended up using the `ignore_options`.

From my Makefile (slightly simplified):

```
CC = ccache ignore_options=-specs=nano.specs arm-none-eabi-gcc
```